# Given a characteristic function find its random variable

Tags: statistics, characteristic-functions

Given this characteristic function: $char(t) = cos(t)/(1+t^2)$ problem asks me to find the expected value and and its variance. I know how to do it using the derivative method.

But, in the solutions this approach is selected: if $X$ is a random variable that corresponds to a given characteristic function, we can decompose it to $X_1 + (X_2 - X_3)$. $X_1$ has uniform distribution (probability $1/2$ to get $-1$ and probability $1/2$ to get $1$). And $X_2$ and $X_3$ are expontentially distributed with parameter $1$.

And following from that, $E[X] = E[X_1] + E[X_2] - E[X_3] = 0 + 1 - 1 = 0$

---

The solution is so elegant. But how to get this decomposition? I understand  that $X_1$ (with uniform distribution) corresponds to $cos(x)$. And others look a lot like exponentially distributed variables.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses properties of the characteristic function. Suppose $\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ are independent random variables with respective characteristic functions $\phi_k$. Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be constants. Then,

$$\phi_{\sum_{k=1}^na_kX_k}(t) = E\left[e^{it\sum_{k=1}^na_kX_k}\right] = E\left[\prod_{k=1}^ne^{ita_kX_k}\right] = \prod_{k=1}^nE\left[e^{ita_kX_k}\right] = \prod_{k=1}^n\phi_k(a_kt).$$

The uniform distribution has characteristic function $\phi_1(t) = \frac{e^{-it}+e^{it}}{2} = \cos(t)$. The unit rate exponential distribution has characteristic $\frac{1}{1 - it}$.

$$\frac{\cos(t)}{1 + t^2} = \cos(t)\left(\frac{1}{1 - it}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-i(-t)}\right),$$

which is the characteristic function of $X_1 + X_2 - X_3$ where $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent, $X_1$ is discrete uniform and $X_2$ and $X_3$ are unit rate exponential functions.

In general, when you are working with Fourier transforms, characteristic functions, Laplace transforms and other things in that vein, the first thing you want to do is try to use the fundamental properties of the transform to turn the function into something you recognize.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks! Just a minor question: why is in the other exponentially distributed term 1-i(-t)? Why it's not just 1-it?

Comment: I understand that this way we obtain $1+t^2$ as asked in the question. But, how are we allowed to do that?

Comment: I just factored the denominator. $(1+t^2) = (1-it)(1+it) = (1-it)(1-i(-t))$. So then we can apply the formula for $X_1$ uniform, $X_2,X_3$ exponential and $a_1 = a_2 = 1$ and $a_3 = -1$.

Comment: Is it because they are two random variables? Even though the lambda is the same, we can change the sign of the $t$ parameter?

Comment: It's because we are looking at independent random variables scaled by a constant. $\frac{1}{1 + it}$ is the characteristic function of $-X$ where $X$ is a unit rate exponentially distributed random variable. Think of it this way. Suppose $X$ is an exponential random variable with mean $1$. Then $X$ has characteristic function $1/(1-it)$. Now, for $\lambda > 0$, $\lambda X$ is an exponential r.v. with mean $\lambda$ and characteristic $1/(1 - \lambda it)$. If $\lambda < 0$, then $\lambda X$ is no longer exponential, but the characteristic function is still $1/(1 - \lambda it)$.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I got the idea fully now.